# Saving a presentation with text highlight in Pdf format

Tags: .net, aspose, aspose-slides

I'm using .NET Aspose.Slides to create a presentation and trying to save the resulting file in PDF format. The problem is the presentation has text highlight that do not appear in the saved pdf file.

In MS Powerpoint there is an option to make sure the highlight is available in the exported pdf. This would be done by checking the checkbox under `Export->Create PDF/XPS->Options->Publish Options`.

Is there an option with Aspose where this could be done?! PDF Options doesn't have any option corresponding to this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the information shared by you, source presentation and generated PDF file needs to be investigated. So that we may investigate it and log an issue if the problem is reproduced on our end. I request you to please make a post over [this link](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.slides-product-family/109/showforum.aspx) and share with us the requested files.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.